# Compute this Laplace and inverse Laplace transform

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform, cauchy-integral-formula

I know that
$$ \mathcal{L}(\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi t}})
=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}|x-\eta|}}{2\sqrt{s}}$$
I am interested in a proof via showing that
$$ \int \frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{st}dt=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}|x-\eta|}}{2\sqrt{s}}$$
 and via
$$ \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}|x-\eta|}}{2\sqrt{s}}e^{st}ds=\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi t}} $$
Just some general indications would be enough.

Comment: edited. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us work on the following integral
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx. $$
Under the change of variable $x=\gamma t$ ($\gamma>0$ will be determined later), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx&=&\gamma\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2\gamma^2t^2-\frac{b^2}{\gamma^2t^2}}dt.
\end{eqnarray}
Letting $a^2\gamma^2=\frac{b^2}{\gamma^2}$ gives $\gamma=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx&=&\gamma\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2\gamma^2t^2-\frac{b^2}{\gamma^2t^2}}dx\\
&=&\gamma\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2\gamma^2t^2-\frac{b^2}{\gamma^2t^2}}dt\\
&=&\gamma\int_0^\infty e^{-ab(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2})}dt\\
&=&\gamma e^{-2ab}\int_0^\infty e^{-ab(t-\frac{1}{t})^2}dt\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}e^{-2ab}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt{ab}}\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a}e^{-2ab}.
\end{eqnarray}
Using this, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{L}(\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi t}})
&=&\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}dt\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-st^2-(x-\eta)^{2}/4t^2}dt\\
&=&\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}|x-\eta|}}{2\sqrt{s}}
\end{eqnarray}